# HexadecimalStringToByteArray() throw exception in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, hex

I am practicing `HexadecimalStringToByteArray()` on `VS2017`. But throw exception. Could you please tell me more information about it?

> An unhandled exception of type
> 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find any recognizable digits.

```cs
public static byte[] HexadecimalStringToByteArray(string input)
{
    var outputLength = input.Length / 2;
    var output = new byte[outputLength];
    using (var sr = new StringReader(input))
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < outputLength; i++)
            output[i] = Convert.ToByte(new string(new char[2] { (char)sr.Read()(char)sr.Read() }), 16);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: the input you gave it could not be parsed. Use the debugger to see if you might have given bad input.
Maybe check if input is null or empty before working on it 
Consider to use try cath to return null if the input is malformated

Comment: `(char)sr.Read()(char)sr.Read()` is not valid C#. Please post your *actual* code, which we can run

Comment: Please also provide an example input which fails

Comment: This appears to work fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NCfGjP

Comment: the input value is too larger encrypted hex value..

Comment: What does "too larger encrypted hex value" mean? Can you post a [mcve] which **includes** the input which causes this function to fail, so that we can run it and see it fail?

Comment: Here the link it is for input
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PvtH6Hyzo-NBRThyKDw3OX29aUoGq5aY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You code (after correcting the syntax error as noted by @canton7) works fine for me with this input.

Comment: I copy/pasted your input into the repro above, and it works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZN5zlP . Voting to close as cannot reproduce.